# Does royal mail have a web API to integrate with to get tracking, label generation

Tags: web-services

Has anyone has any experience integrating with royal mail in UK.

Searching their site [Royal Mail](http://www.royalmail.com/portal/rm) does not reveal anything

Comment: I am looking for the same- but it looks like I will use some sort of scraping mechanism and make my own API... there is no capcha on many things there.

Comment: http://www.royalmail.com/parcel-despatch-medium/uk-delivery/parcel-shipping-solutions/shipping-api